# Make emacs explicitly copy to/from the X11 selection and clipboard buffers?

Tags: emacs, clipboard

In [vim](https://superuser.com/a/119106/3948) you can explicitly copy/paste to/from the X11 selection buffer and clipboard buffer by using `"*y` and `"+y`, respectively.

My emacs is (apparently -- it's not intentional on my part) set up to use the selection buffer for `C-w`, `C-y`, and friends.

Are there functions that I can call, analogous to `kill-region` and `yank` which use the clipboard buffer?

To be clear, I want selective access to both buffers at the same time. Based on some quick web searches, it looks like there are configuration variables I can set which will globally change `yank` to use one buffer or the other. I want to be able to select, just like vim's `*` and `+` registers allow.

*(Hopefully I've gotten the terminology right: when I say "selection buffer", I mean the buffer where you can highlight text with the mouse and middle-click to paste. When I say "clipboard buffer", I mean the place where text goes when copied by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> in non-emacs apps.)*

**Edit**: bzg's answer is really close.

In gnome-terminal, I select ~/projects with the mouse, then
right-mouse -> copy. Then I select /home. Still in gnome-terminal, when I do:

- middle-mouse: /home
- right-mouse -> paste: ~/projects

When I move into emacs and do:

- middle-mouse: /home
- M-y (yank): /home
- C-S-y (my-yank): ~/projects

Great! `yank` uses the selection buffer and `my-yank` uses the clipboard.

Now, still in emacs, I do:

- C-SPC M-f M-f C-w (make region "regular kill", and kill it)

then go to gnome-terminal and do:

- middle-mouse: "regular kill"
- right-mouse -> paste: ~/projects

Great! Only the selection buffer was changed, not the clipboard.

Then, back in emacs, I do:

- C-SPC M-f M-f C-S-w (make region "my kill", and kill it)

then go to gnome-terminal and do:

- middle-mouse: regular kill
- right-mouse -> paste: ~/projects

That's wrong, the clipboard buffer should contain "my kill".

My `interprogram-cut-function` is `x-select-text`. My `x-select-enable-clipboard` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bzg's answer comes really close, but the toggling of `interprogram-cut-function` doesn't quite do the trick -- I believe it ends up `nil` because that variable has a value when the function starts.

This revised set of functions does exactly what I want, by explicitly setting the clipboard/primary enables in each one. Big hat tip to bzg for getting me on the right track!

```
(defun my-yank (&optional arg)
  "Yank from the clipboard, not the primary selection."
  (interactive "*P")
  (let ((x-select-enable-clipboard t)
        (x-select-enable-primary nil))
    (yank arg)))

(defun my-kill-region (beg end)
  "Kill to the clipboard, not the primary selection."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((x-select-enable-clipboard t)
        (x-select-enable-primary nil))
    (kill-region beg end)))

(defun my-kill-ring-save (beg end)
  "Save to the clipboard, not the primary selection."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((x-select-enable-clipboard t)
        (x-select-enable-primary nil))
    (kill-ring-save beg end)))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-S-w") 'my-kill-region)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-M-S-w") 'my-kill-ring-save)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-S-y") 'my-yank)
```

Comment: `my-kill-region` should be `(interactive "*r")` - because `kill-region` modifies the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

This code will map <kbd>C-S-y</kbd> and <kbd>C-S-w</kbd> to customized versions of `yank` and `kill-region` that will temporarily toggle the use of clipboard:

```
(defun my-yank (&optional arg)
  (interactive "*P")
  (let ((x-select-enable-clipboard (not x-select-enable-clipboard)))
    (yank arg)))

(defun my-kill-region (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((interprogram-cut-function
     (when (not (eq interprogram-cut-function 'x-select-text))
       'x-select-text)))
    (kill-region beg end)))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-S-w") 'my-kill-region)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-S-y") 'my-yank)
```

So if you copied something in X and don't want it when yanking in Emacs, use <kbd>C-S-y</kbd>.  If you kill something in Emacs and don't want it in the X clipboard, use <kbd>C-S-w</kbd>.

All this assuming you are using the default values for `x-select-enable-clipboard' and`interprogram-cut-function', of course.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! You got me pointed in the right direction. If you see the edit to my question, one of the test cases fails. Your `my-kill-region` doesn't put anything in the clipboard. See my answer with revisions to your functions for a working version.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs provides some useful functions in `menu-bar.el`, of all places.  So I have:

```
 (global-set-key [(control shift ?w)] 'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
 (global-set-key [(control shift ?y)] 'clipboard-yank)
```